# Sens an SMS with PDU format from a Mobile Broadband Module

Tags: c#, sms

Here is my problem: I would like to send an sms from a Mobile Broadband Module via a c# code.

After a lot of researches, I found how to detect the module, unlock the pin code, access all the information (Home Provider, Service Center Address, ...). But when I comes to send the message, nothing happens. I tried to create the PDU message using an online tool : http://www.smartposition.nl/resources/sms_pdu.html
But it doesn't seem very effective.

Here is my code :

```
            //Get the interface manager
            MbnInterfaceManager manager = new MbnInterfaceManager();
            //Make it usable
            IMbnInterfaceManager infMgr = (IMbnInterfaceManager)manager;
            try
            {
                //Get all interfaces
                IMbnInterface[] interfaces = infMgr.GetInterfaces() as IMbnInterface[];

                if (interfaces.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (IMbnInterface interf in interfaces)
                    {
                        //Write its information
                        Console.WriteLine("State : " + interf.GetReadyState());

                        //Get the Pin
                        IMbnPinManager pinMan = interf as IMbnPinManager;
                        IMbnPin pin = pinMan.GetPinList().GetValue(0) as IMbnPin;
                        uint requestID;
                        //Unlock Sim
                        pin.Enter("MyPinCode", out requestID);

                        Thread.Sleep(10000);

                        Console.WriteLine("Home Provider : " + interf.GetHomeProvider().providerName);
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection ID : " + interf.GetConnection().ConnectionID);
                        //Create an object sms
                        IMbnSms sms = interf as IMbnSms;
                        //Get its information
                        IMbnSmsConfiguration smsConfig = sms.GetSmsConfiguration();
                        //Get capabilities of the interface
                        MBN_INTERFACE_CAPS caps = interf.GetInterfaceCapability();
                        //get SMS capabilities and cast it
                        MBN_SMS_CAPS scaps = (MBN_SMS_CAPS)caps.smsCaps;

                        //Show capabilities and other info
                        //SMS CAPS returns 3, which means PDU receive and send
                        Console.WriteLine("SMS CAP : " + scaps.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Service center address : " + smsConfig.ServiceCenterAddress);
                        MBN_SMS_STATUS_INFO smsInfo = new MBN_SMS_STATUS_INFO();
                        sms.GetSmsStatus(out smsInfo);

                        //Send a message with a pdu format
                        //You can know the format to use with the SMS CAPS

                        string pduData = "0692600600030011000A9270684803880000AA19C2B75BFDAECB41EA32685E4FCF417537485E7687E5644";
                        //Get the byte size of the message
                        byte[] bytesize = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pduData);
                        //Send sms
                        sms.SmsSendPdu(pduData, (byte) bytesize.Length, out requestID);
                        Console.WriteLine("Sending sms ....");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No connection found");
                }
            }
            catch (COMException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.HResult + "\n" + e.Message + "\n" + e.Source);
            }
```

This code works until the part supposed to send the SMS.

Where can I find an offline converter to get my PDU message dynamically, and for the one I'm trying to send currently, why isn't it working ?

Comment: Change following : sms.SmsSendPdu(bytesize, bytesize.Length, out requestID);  You need to send the byte array and not to truncate the length to 256.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the problem is that I have to send the pdu message as a string and the size as a byte, how do I do ?

Comment: The code doesn't make sense.  You are using GetBytes() to get a byte[] and then length.  But then you are passing the string.  Why?  The length needs to be consistent with the data.  You cannot get byte length and then pass the string.  The sizes are different.

Comment: Oh okay, I see ! So I have to get the length of pduData itself ? and is the message correct or do I have to change something ?

Comment: Do not know.  It depends on what the SmsSendPdu() method needs.